# Server Error in '/WebSite8' Application. Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Description:**

An exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

```
System.Argument Out Of Range Exception: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

**Code:**

```
  protected void ImageButton1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        ImageButton lnkbtn = sender as ImageButton;
        GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        
        
           string filePath = GridView2.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

            Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
            Response.End();
        
    }
```

Comment: This `gvrow.RowIndex` is probably -1, because the row is not selected to get a value

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you are facing issue at this point

```
string filePath = GridView2.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

When you are trying to pull out Value of datakey the GVrow.RowIndex is having value greater than element count.

Try to debug and see what is count of element and what gvrow.RowIndex is setting up.